AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'compiled'
I use GridSearch to optimize LSTM with different combinations of hyperparameters.
This is my code.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
# from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
# from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM


data = pd.read_excel('tsmc_stock_data.xlsx', index_col=0)

data['Return'] = data['Close'].pct_change()
data['Volatility'] = data['Return'].rolling(window=5).std()
data.dropna(inplace=True) 

data = data[['Close', 'SMA_5', 'SMA_10', 'SMA_20', 'SMA_50', 'Return', 'Volatility']]

data_values = data.values

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data_values)


def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    X, Y = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset) - look_back):
        a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), :]
        X.append(a)
        Y.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(X), np.array(Y)

look_back = 30
X, y = create_dataset(scaled_data, look_back)


train_size = int(len(X) * 0.8)
X_train, X_test = X[:train_size], X[train_size:]
y_train, y_test = y[:train_size], y[train_size:]


def build_model(lstm_units=50, optimizer='adam'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(lstm_units, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(look_back, X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(LSTM(lstm_units, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(25))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model

model = KerasRegressor(model=build_model, verbose=0)

param_grid = {
    'model__lstm_units': [25, 50, 75],  # LSTM units
    'model__optimizer': ['adam', 'rmsprop'],  # Optimizers
    'batch_size': [16, 32],  # Batch sizes
    'epochs': [10, 50]  # Number of epochs
}
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)


print("Best score: {:.4f}".format(grid_result.best_score_))
print("Best parameters: {}".format(grid_result.best_params_))


best_model = build_model(
    lstm_units=grid_result.best_params_['model__lstm_units'],
    optimizer=grid_result.best_params_['model__optimizer']
)
best_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=grid_result.best_params_['epochs'], batch_size=grid_result.best_params_['batch_size'], verbose=1)


best_model.save('tsmc_lstm_best_model.h5')
np.save('scaler.npy', scaler.scale_)
np.save('min.npy', scaler.min_)
np.save('data_shape.npy', np.array(data.shape))

print("SAVE~")

I have tried many versions of Keras and TensorFlow, but the compatibility issues remain.
I get the following error when the following code was executed.
ValueError:
All the 72 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
72 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 888, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 770, in fit
    self._fit(
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 928, in _fit
    self._ensure_compiled_model()
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 439, in _ensure_compiled_model
    if not self.model_.compiled:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'compiled'

I'm also curious if there are any errors in my IMPORT.

I tried installing Scikeras with TensorFlow version 2.17, and the code
executed successfully. Please refer to this gist, and let me know if you're
still facing any issues.
